# We have a PrintServer with about 20 subnets and I need to go through them and verify schema and reassign those outside the schema

Tags: powershell, server, active-directory, ip-address, powershell-ise

I posted something similar to this last week, but this is evolved into something a little more complicated. This should be a two-fold operation. First, on the PrintServer, then, deployed across 100-200 machines. I am working on a PSise script (pretty much my first time) that should be able to disseminate and group all the subnet addresses by 3rd octet. Then it should then it should determine if the attached printers and their ports meet the new schema requirement that the 4th octet be within the range of 50-60. If not, determine the next available address within the proper subnet and range, and reassign the ports to the next one available. I will need to track the changes of each subnet so the user machines will line up with the changes made to the print server. So if the PrintServer has 192.168.1.23 >> 192.168.2.50 && 192.168.3.105 >> 192.168.3.52, this same change needs to happen for all machines in subnets 1 and 3 respectively.

I know this function probably is not setup correctly, so if I have things out of place, feel free to let me know. I get the feeling all the code that should be performing the changes should go in the -end of the processing -begin, -process, -end segment.

Here's the code I have so far, and I am getting some values that I would expect. I'm just not getting them into proper arrays and piping them down for further use. I have a feeling I may need a -join somewhere, but like I said, I do not have any experience with Powershell.

```
function verify-printerport
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [OutputType([int])]
    Param
    (
        # Param1 help description
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
                   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,
                   Position=0)]
        $third = @{},
        $fourth = @{},
        $thirds = @{},
        $fourths = @{},

        # Param2 Gets WMI Object -Class -ExtendedProperty -Sorts
        $set1 = ( Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_TCPIPPrinterPort | select -ExpandProperty HostAddress | sort )

    )

    Begin
    { 
        $set1
        $thirds = @{0=100, 202, 203, 204, 209, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230}
        $fourths = @{49=50..60}
    }
    Process
    {
        foreach ($ips in $set1) 
        {
            Where 
            {
                (($ips.HostAddress -Split '\.')[2] -contains $thirds)
            } |

            ForEach ($getThird) 
            {
                $third.Add($getThird.IndexOf($ips.HostAddress),$getThird.ToArray)  

                    where 
                    {
                        $getThird.ForEach($ips.HostAddress[2] -eq $thirds)
                    }
            }
        }

        foreach ($ips2 in $set1) {
            where 
            {
                (($ips2.HostAddress -split '\.')[3] -notcontains $fourths)
            } |

            foreach ($getFourth) 
            {
                $fourth.Add($getFourth,$inRange.Length) 

                if ( $getFourth.foreach($set1.HostAddress -split '\.'[3] -lt 50) -or
                        $getFourth.foreach($set1.HostAddress -split '\.'[3] -gt 60))
                {
                    where 
                    {
                        ($set1.ForEach($inRange.HostAddress -split '\.')[3] -contains $fourths) 
                    }

                    set $inRange.StartsWith($set1.Length)
                        $inRange.Length ++
                }

                foreach ($inRange in $getFourth) 
                {
                    if ($inRange.ForEach($setRange.HostAddress -split '\.'[3] -contains $fourths))
                    {
                        $inRange.GetLength($setRange.GetValue($setRange.Length)) 
                    }
                }
                $inRange += $set1.Length 
            }
        }   
    }
    End
    {

    }
}
```

$thirds and $fourths referring to 3rd/4th octet. $thirds is all the subnets we have. $fourths is the range all printers should be.

Any help you can offer would be greatly appreciated. It's taken me several days and long hours just to get here and I'm about at wit's end. Some of this is derived from searches, other from my other post, some from me trying to apply some of my other programming experience (fyi, I'm still in school) and a lot of it just plain guess work. Thanks in advance for taking the time!

Comment: You may be better off breaking this down into smaller parts and testing them seperately, for instance your parameter sets don't really seem like they could take different values from what you are assigning by default, so should be moved into your `Begin` Block.  Also you are using hash tables `@{}` where it looks like you intend to be using arrays `@()`.  going lower your where-object filter is checking to see if your IP address contains `$Thirds` and it should probably be the other way around.  Your piped foreach loops are also using an invalid syntax.

Comment: @Mike - Thanks for the input. I was wondering if the array format was the better method for this. If I understand you correctly, I should assign my '@()' in the 'Begin' block and remove them from 'param' or just assign the 'param' and assign its value in the 'Begin'? Do you also mean I should see if the $Thirds contains the IP and what syntax is incorrect in my loops? I am very inexperienced with this.

Comment: Since your new at this you should really break this down into smaller parts and get those working first, then put them together, trying to jump in and write and advanced function without getting the basics down is going to give you trouble.  just try to create a script that loops through all IP addresses on a host and prints them to the console, then start adding additional pieces(and ignore advanced functions for now, a basic function is fine for this purpose).  unfortunately the large number of issues and syntax problems means it's pretty hard to help you with this over comments on SO.

Comment: Here are a few links you should take a look at, work your way through them and make sure your comfortable with the concepts before moving on to the next one.  Everything will make more sense once you've mastered some of the more basic concepts.  [Loops](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/04/28/basics-of-powershell-looping-foreach/)  [Filtering](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2007.04.powershell.aspx)  [comparisons](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.0/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators)

Comment: I'll look at those, again really appreciate it. I did start them in smaller chunks and got it mostly working section by section, but when I put them together, they really kind of fell apart.